# Understanding link pseudo class inheritence

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a simple setup with a:link, a:visited a:hover and a:active all defined at the top of my style sheet. I also have a div where I've defined an a:link color for anchors inside of it. When I do this those links do not inherit the remaining pseudo classes for hover and active.... until I click that div's link and it has thus been "visited", at which point the pseudo classes start working. Why is this?

the CSS...

```
a:link {
    color: blue;
}

a:visited {
    color: purple
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}

a:active {
    color: pink;
}

#theDiv a:link {
    color: green;
}
```

the HTML...

```
<a href="#33">The First Link</a>
<div id="theDiv">
    <a href="#33">The Second Link</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKztj/7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#theDiv a:link` has a higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than all your other selectors and is overriding them until the link no longer matches the `:link` selector, at which point it matches the `:visited` selector.

Comment: I see. I had always thought of the anchor pseudo classes as being independent of each other in regards to inheritance. Your answer has helped me to realize that the anchor rather assumes inheritance based on it's state, primarily :link and :visited — would that be correct?

Answer (score 0):

All browsers set a default style for anchor elements.
You need a more specific selector to override:

```
#theDiv a:hover {color:red}
```